# Regex to not match a particular character or match empty

Tags: regex, mongodb

My list of strings are,

```
1. bc     // should match
2. abc    // should not match
3. bc-bc  // should match
4. ab-bc  // should match
5. bc-ab  // should match
```

I want to match all `bc`s. If it starts with any other character like `a` in string 1, I don't want to match.

I tried with regex `[^a]bc`. It did not match string 2 as well as string 1 and 5, since `[]` expects a character. Then I did try with `[^a]?bc`. It matched string 2 also. How to make regex which matches empty or not a particular list of characters?

Comment: `(?<!a)(bc)` Try negative look behind.

Comment: Use [`/\bbc\b/`](https://regex101.com/r/OtEb9K/1) if you want to match whole words `bc`.

Comment: @MYGz That did not work with perl. I got `Invalid regular expression` error

Comment: Please show the Perl code you're using. Wiktor's regex is correct.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Cool. That worked. But If I don't want to match a list of characters and can match any other characters and empty, how it will be possible?

Comment: Please read the answer I provided below.

Comment: To match chars other than those you want to define, use a negated character class.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Sorry I should've mentioned. I was using with mongodb. Since MongoDB uses Perl compatible regular expressions, I mentioned `perl` there

Comment: In MongoDB, you may use PCRE regex, not Perl one.

Comment: OK, I corrected the tags on your question.

Comment: I think the real problem is quite different from the sample texts provided. If `\bbc\b` does not work in 100% cases, please explain what you need supplying more real life texts to test.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry my mistake.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: And depending on how you use them, you can only use JavaScript regexes sometimes. Which would explain why the lookbehind regex isn't working for him. To OP: That's why you're supposed to always provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thank you. I will take care of these notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to match `bc` only if it's not preceded by a certain set of characters (like for example `a`, `x`, or `y`)? Then that's exactly what a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is for:

```
(?<![axy])bc
```

will match `bc` or `bbc`, but not `abc` or `ybc`.

If you want to match `bc` as a complete "word", i. e. not adjacent to any letters or digits, use [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
\bbc\b
```

Note that in MongoDB, in order to be able to use features like lookbehind that are available only to the PCRE engine (and not to JavaScript), you need to follow a certain syntax (using strings instead of regex objects), for example:

```
{ name: { $regex: '(?<![axy])bc' } }
```